How can I make formAction of useFormState to accept an argument?
I want formAction to accept an argument for formData, else it will be submitted as undefined. Tho, I can only wrap the action={} into formAction but I want to utilize the benefits of useOptimistic.
export const PostForm = ({ posts }: { posts: Data[]}) => {

  type Post = Pick<Data, "title" | "content">
  console.log(posts)


  const [formState, formAction] = useFormState(createPost, {
    message: null,
    errors: {}
  });

  const [optimisticState, addOptimistic] = useOptimistic<Post[], Post>(
    posts,
    (currentState, optimisticValue) => {
      return [...currentState, optimisticValue]
    }
  )

  return (
    <>
      <form action={async (formData: FormData) => {
        addOptimistic({
          title: formData.get('title') as string,
          content: formData.get('content') as string
        })
        formAction(formData) // < -- Expected 0 arguments, but got 1
      }}>

        <PostInput state={formState} />
      </form>

      {
        optimisticState.map((m, k) => (<div key={k}>{m.title}</div>))
      }
    </>

  )

}

